# How to handle large amount of dynamic path when using next.js getStaticPaths?

Tags: next.js

In `next.js` `getStaticPaths` runs in build time, but imagine if you have large amount of dynamic path

```
url/[id_1]
url/[id_2]
url/[id_3]
url/[id_4]
url/[id_5]
...
url/[id_1million]
```

it seems like building all `id` will not scale (server disk size, and build time), how do you handle this case?

Is there a `getServerSideProps` equivalent of `getStaticPaths` like `getServerSidePaths`?

I plan to pregenerate top 1k popular id, but it would not be feasible to pre generate all 5 million+ id.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This would be a good scenario for incremental static regeneration (ISR). You could statically generate only the top pages that you need. If a user requests a page that is not built yet, what would happen is that Next.js will server-render that page only on the first request and then, it will be cached for subsequent requests.

Use this with `fallback: true` if you want to show some sort of fallback UI while the page is being server-rendered (using `router.isFallback` on the component) or with `fallback: 'blocking'`.

You can read more details about how this works [here](https://nextjs.org/docs/basic-features/data-fetching/incremental-static-regeneration).

Comment: I read through the doc, but wasn't too sure if `getStaticProps` will be called for new ids encountered? Or do I have to implement `getServerSideProps` ?

Comment: You don't need `getServerSideProps`. If a new id is added to the database, and there is a request to a page with that id, Next.js will server-render the page at first request, so yes, `getStaticProps` will be called. Consider ISR some sort of hybrid between SSR and SSG.